# Annotate file based on another in R - dplyr or tidyverse

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have a question similar to this one:

[Add column(Annotate) one data frame based on column from other data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49330462/add-columnannotate-one-data-frame-based-on-column-from-other-data-frame-in-r)

Where I have two files as such:

```
head(geno)

chr     Pos             Val
X       129271111       10
X       129271112       10
X       129271113       10
X       129271114       10
X       129271115       10
```

And

```
head(anno)

chr Annot  start       end         
X   promo  129271053   129271110   
X   Fx12   129270618   129270706   
X   Txw    129270020   129270160   
X   Tx3    129267288   129267430   
X   Tx5    129265650   129265774
```

And I would like to add a 4th column (Annot from the second file) to the first file based on whether the Pos variable lies between the start and end of the second file.

The only thing I can think of is using a loop to do this and that seems like a real waste of time as the files are so large.

Can someone please provide some advise on how to do this in a tidyverse/dplyr way?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way - assuming that the start and end ranges don't overlap.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

geno %>%
  mutate(Annot = anno$Annot[map_dbl(Pos, ~ which(.x >= anno$start & .x <= anno$end) %>% 
                                      replace(length(.) == 0, NA))])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this in base R which doesn't require loops (including the loops hidden away inside `apply` type functions). That is to use a combination of `outer` and `which`. Again, it depends on there being a unique answer for each row of `geno`.

I have altered your example slightly, since none of the `Pos` values actually match any of the `start` - `end` ranges in the data in the initial question.

**Data:**

```r
geno
#>   chr       Pos Val
#> 1   X 129265661  10
#> 2   X 129267289  10
#> 3   X 129270628  10
#> 4   X 129270033  10
#> 5   X 129271073  10

anno
#>   chr Annot     start       end
#> 1   X promo 129271053 129271110
#> 2   X  Fx12 129270618 129270706
#> 3   X   Txw 129270020 129270160
#> 4   X   Tx3 129267288 129267430
#> 5   X   Tx5 129265650 129265774
```

**Code:**

```r
geno$Annot <- anno$Annot[which(outer(anno$end, geno$Pos, `>`) & 
                               outer(anno$start, geno$Pos, `<`), 
                               arr.ind = TRUE)[, 1]]
```

**Result**

```r
geno
#>   chr       Pos Val Annot
#> 1   X 129265661  10   Tx5
#> 2   X 129267289  10   Tx3
#> 3   X 129270628  10  Fx12
#> 4   X 129270033  10   Txw
#> 5   X 129271073  10 promo
```

Comment: @h3ab74 I guess this means that geno$Pos contains values that are within the range of multiple rows of your lookup. Have you checked this?